# Eclipse: Show author of each line in editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, atlassian-fisheye

I'd like to show the name of the author of each line in my Java files.
I am already using FishEye (http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) but I'd like to have this feature within my Eclipse Java editor.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a similar feature in Eclipse: select Team / Show Annotation... in the right click menu on a Java file. It should work with various team providers (I only have experiences with CSV and SVN).

Short description of this feature is available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120610215329/http://www.vasanth.in/2006/05/22/eclipse-tip-cvs-quick-diff-annotations/).

*UPDATE*: for the Eclipse EGit team provider, the corresponding menu is called Team / Show revision information. See more information in the excellent [EGit User Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide).

Comment: How do you get "Team - Show Annotation" to show up? I don't have that option. I have Egit installed and "Team - Show in history" but not "Annotation".

Comment: @user2568374 I´m having the sam problem did you solve that issue?

Comment: @xiidarkevil got it this way: “Team->Show In History” does not appear for file right click:
1. Right click on Project package
2. Select Team - share project
3. Select git
4. Select User or create repository in parent folder of project
5. Select folder with one dot (.git) + finish
6. right click file for history, right click text area and select

Answer (score 10):

As of (at least) Eclipse Oxygen, "Show Annotation" is no longer on the Team menu.

The menu has been renamed "Show Revision Information", and is located at the bottom of the Team menu.

[image]

Comment: To hide the revision information, right click into the revision information -> "Revisions"  -> "Hide Revision Information". Clicking "Show Revision Information" will NOT hide the revision information! I find this to be a very un-intuitive menu!

Answer (score 6):

In Eclipse right click on your java class.

`Team -> Show Revision Information`

then right click on the line numbers

`Revisions -> Show Author`

this will give the name of authors for each line.